# How can I use Gekko's m.if3 attribute to write a conditional function with multiple cases?

Tags: conditional-statements, gekko

I am using Gekko to simulate a differential algebraic equation system containing conditional functions, but I am not sure how to reproduce a conditional function with multiple cases using `m.if3` attribute. Can anyone help me? In the image the conditional function, I'm trying to write.

[image: Conditional function with multiple cases]

I have tried with this code.

```
p_prime_v_case1 = a*(0.4 + 0.4*a)/(v_max*((a+1)*0.4)**2)
p_prime_v_case2 = a*(1+0.4*a+1.2*v/v_max + 0.6*(v/v_max)**2)/(v_max*((a-v/v_max)*(1+0.6*v/v_max))**2)
p_prime_v_case3 = (0.4*a+1)/(a*v_max)
p_prime_v_case4 = 1/(v_max)*m.exp(-alpha_G*((v-v_1)/v_max)**alpha_P)*((0.4*a+1)/a + alpha_G*alpha_P*(1+(0.4*a+1)/(a*v_max))*((v-v_1)/v_max)**(alpha_P-1))
p_prime_v_cond1 = m.if3(v+v_max-0.000001, p_prime_v_case1, p_prime_v_case2)
p_prime_v_cond2 = m.if3(v -0.000001, p_prime_v_cond1, p_prime_v_case3)
m.Equation(p_prime_v == m.if3(v-v_1-0.000001, p_prime_v_cond2, p_prime_v_case4))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three `m.if3()` statements that produce a `1` or `0`. The cases are triggered by a combination of the conditions. Here is a simplified demonstration of the logic that is required:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,1,21)

v = m.Param(7)
vmax = 20
v1 = 5

cond1 = m.if3(v+vmax,1,0)
cond2 = m.if3(v,1,0)
cond3 = m.if3(v-v1,1,0)

case1 = m.Intermediate(1.1 * cond1)
case2a = m.Intermediate(2.1 * (1-cond1)*cond2*(1-cond3))
case2b = m.Intermediate(2.1 * (1-cond1)*cond2*cond3)
case3 = m.Intermediate(3.1 * (1-cond1)*(1-cond2)*cond3)
case4 = m.Intermediate(4.1 * (1-cond1)*(1-cond2)*(1-cond3))

p_prime = m.Var()
m.Equation(p_prime == case1+case2a+case2b+case3+case4)

m.solve()

print(f'cond 1: {cond1.value[0]}')
print(f'cond 2: {cond2.value[0]}')
print(f'cond 3: {cond3.value[0]}')

print(f'case 1: {case1.value[0]}')
print(f'case 2: {case1.value[0]}')
print(f'case 3: {case1.value[0]}')
print(f'case 4: {case1.value[0]}')
print(f'p_prime: {p_prime.value[0]}')
```

- `v=m.Param(-25)`: case 1 is selected and the solution is `1.1`.
- `v=m.Param(-15)`: case 2 is selected and the solution is `2.1`.
- `v=m.Param(2)`: case 3 is selected and the solution is `3.1`.
- `v=m.Param(7)`: case 4 is selected and the solution is `4.1`.

For future questions, please provide a complete and minimal example.